# How do I determine if a button is held before an AutoHotkey script is launched?

Tags: autohotkey

I have a script with two subroutines: **A** and **B**. I want **A** to run if I launch the `.ahk` script regularly (by double clicking its icon). and I want **B** to run if I launch the `.ahk` script while a button (say, Ctrl) is held down (while double clicking the icon). Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to detect if a key was pressed *before* the script started, but you can use [GetKeyState](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm) to check if a key is in the "pressed" state when the script starts:

```
if GetKeyState("Ctrl")
    MsgBox Holding Ctrl
else
    MsgBox Not holding Ctrl
```

Comment: Unless another script is watching.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you!
FakeRainBrigand, how do you watch a script?